# JavaFx: How to make 'Tooltip' bigger?

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I set tooltip for buttons,but it looks so small(font size),how can I make it bigger?I have tried `myTooltip.setFont(new Font(20))`,but it dosen't work,why?And how can I make the font bigger?
Thank you all guys!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Set the [style](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#tooltip) in a stylesheet, or directly, e. g.:

```
tooltip.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 20");
```

Comment: Thank you ! It is helpful !

Comment: Changing that for an existing tooltip, already shown before, looks different from a tooltip freshly created with that style applied: the border size is different. Otherwise this still works fine. I also tried to scale the whole tooltip (via its styleable node - `getStyleableNode()`) but with that the whole application became very laggy (no idea why exactly).